# making lists in a dictionary by user inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'am a newbee in python and coding, and I really don't understand why my program isn't working correctly. The expected effect is "name wants to go to [destinations]" while my code doesn't distinguish different "{names : [destinations]}" pairs.

Here's my code, thanks for your attention here :)

```
response = {}
destinations = []
ptname = 'name pls.'
prompt = 'input some places in the world, input next to go to the next user'
active = True
unfinished = True
while active:
  unfinished = True
  name = input(ptname)
  while unfinished:
    destination = input(prompt)
    if destination != 'next':
      destinations.append(destination)
      print(destination + ' has been added to your list.')
      response[name] = destinations
    elif destination == 'next':
      unfinished = False
  go_on = input('wish to continue? y/n')
  if go_on == 'n':
    active = False

print(response)
for name, destinations in response.items():
  print(name + ' wants to go to ')
  for destination in destinations:
    print(destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to reset (actually create a new reference) for `destinations` in the same outer loop where you set `name` or you're be reusing the same list for all names.

```
  name = input(ptname)
  destinations = []   # create new reference for the list
  while unfinished:
  ...
```

Comment: how can I generate new lists within the while=unfinished loop, and how to index new list names with user 'name's in the dictionary {response}